# Get ROWCOUNT for all actions performed in MERGE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, ssis, etl

I amazed myself with this `MERGE` statement,  the company isn't truly doing a *Type 2 Slowing Changing Dimension* but close. Oddly it's not even analytical data but let's ignore that horrendous decision. I have this working referencing `HashBytes` to indicated changed rows. Unfortunately, to get all scenarios addressed I ended up with that additional `INSERT` at then end from the temp table which actually holds the updated rows.

Alas it's functional but if you have a more effective design, please do share. I would appreciate it.

However, I am attempting to get a `row count` representing not only for the `INSERT` from the `Temp` table, but the updates AND the new `INSERTS`, all are distinct separate actions with their own `row count`, that I need to document and account for.

How can I do this, please ?

```
DECLARE @dtNow AS DATETIME = GetDate()
DECLARE @dtPast AS DATETIME = DATEADD(day,-1,GetDate())
DECLARE @dtFuture AS DATETIME = '22991231'
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- Temp Table is JUST Updating Rows reflecting 
--Historical Marker on existing row No content change to row's columnar     content data 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TheTempTableName') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE     #TheTempTableName


CREATE TABLE #TheTempTableName 
(
    ABunchOfColumns
    RowCreatedDate datetime NULL,
    RowEffectiveDate datetime NULL,
    RowTerminationDate datetime NULL,
    RowIsCurrent bit NULL,
    RowHash varchar(max) NULL,
)

INSERT INTO #TheTempTableName
(
            ABunchOfColumns
                ,RowCreatedDate
                ,RowEffectiveDate
                ,RowTerminationDate
                ,RowIsCurrent
                ,RowHash 
)


SELECT
                ABunchOfColumns
                ,RowCreatedDate
                ,RowEffectiveDate
                ,RowTerminationDate
                ,RowIsCurrent
                ,RowHash 
FROM
    (
        MERGE tblDim WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target
            USING 
            (
                SELECT          
                ABunchOfColumns
                ,RowCreatedDate
                ,RowEffectiveDate
                ,RowTerminationDate
                ,RowIsCurrent
                ,RowHash 

                FROM dbo.tblStaging
            )       
        AS source
        ON target.PKID  = source.PKID       
        WHEN MATCHED
            AND target.RowIsCurrent = 1
            AND target.RowHash != source.RowHash                    
------- PROCESS ONE -- UPDATE --- HISTORICALLY MARK EXISTING ROWS
            THEN UPDATE SET                     
                    RowEffectiveDate    =   @dtPast
                    ,RowTerminationDate =   @dtPast
                    ,RowIsCurrent   =   0                   
-----  PROCESS TWO -- INSERT ---INSERT NEW ROWS
            WHEN NOT     MATCHED                                                          
            THEN INSERT    ---   THIS INSERT Goes directly into Target ( DIM     ) Table (New Rows not matched with PK = PK ) 
                (
                ABunchOfColumns
                ,RowCreatedDate
                ,RowEffectiveDate
                ,RowTerminationDate
                ,RowIsCurrent
                ,RowHash 
                )
                VALUES
                (                   
                source.ABunchOfColumns
                    ,@dtNow                 --source.RowCreatedDate,
                    ,@dtFuture              ---source.RowEffectiveDate,
                    ,@dtFuture              ---source.RowTerminationDate,
                    ,1                      ---source.RowIsCurrent,
                    ,source.RowHash
                )
-------PROCESS THREE a  -- INSERT ---OUTPUT MATCHED ROWS FROM PROCESS ONE THAT CAUSED     HISTORICAL MARK (CHANGES) "INSERT"
        OUTPUT 
        $action Action_Out,

                ABunchOfColumns
                ,RowCreatedDate
                ,RowEffectiveDate
                ,RowTerminationDate
                ,RowIsCurrent
                ,RowHash 
    )       
    AS MERGE_OUT
WHERE MERGE_OUT.Action_Out = 'UPDATE';

----------PROCESS THREE b  -- INSERT FROM Temp Tbl to final
--Now we flush the data in the temp table into dim table

INSERT INTO tblDim
    (
                ABunchOfColumns
                ,RowCreatedDate
                ,RowEffectiveDate
                ,RowTerminationDate
                ,RowIsCurrent
                ,RowHash 
    )
SELECT
         ABunchOfColumns
        ,@dtNow AS RowCreatedDate
        ,@dtFuture AS RowEffectiveDate
        ,@dtFuture AS RowTerminationDate
        ,1 AS RowIsCurrent
        ,RowHash

FROM #TheTempTableName  
END
```

Comment: Hopefully you're aware that you can do exactly the same thing with simpler code with seperate INSERT/UPDATE statements. Personally I avoid using MERGE and here's one reason: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/ Lastly be aware that any hashing algorithm can have collisions (two different sets of data result in the same hash). So in answer to "a more effective design" I suggest seperate INSERT/UPDATE but it's really just opinion on whether thats more effective or not

Answer (score 7):

There are two types of deletes (1) real deletes (2) primary key updates.
So you can also say there are two types of inserts (1) real inserts (2) primary key updates
The updates are always updates.

The dilemma then is when is an insert/delete combination is really an update.

Usually if you dont really care about the one above a simple merge like this is sufficient

```
MERGE esqlProductTarget T
USING esqlProductSource S
ON (S.ProductID = T.ProductID)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE
     SET    T.Name = S.Name,
            T.ProductNumber = S.ProductNumber,
            T.Color = S.Color
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN INSERT (ProductID, Name, ProductNumber, Color)
     VALUES (S.ProductID, S.Name, S.ProductNumber, S.Color)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
THEN DELETE
OUTPUT S.ProductID, $action into @MergeLog;

SELECT MergeAction, Cnt=count(*)
FROM   @MergeLog
GROUP BY MergeAction
```

The output will be like:

```
+-------------+-----+--+
| MergeAction | Cnt |  |
+-------------+-----+--+
| DELETE      | 100 |  |
| UPDATE      |  60 |  |
| INSERT      |  70 |  |
+-------------+-----+--+
```

Refer to https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-merge-statement/

I am not sure why you have "WHERE MERGE_OUT.Action_Out = 'UPDATE'.  But if you remove that, then you can get your rowcount.  Unless I have misunderstood your query.

Comment: I appreciate the insight and your time. in this case DELETE is retire, update row to retired. That means UPDATE (retire) existing  and INSERT new.    My TEMP tbl houses rows that must be INSERTED to the DIM table. Goal is to house and identify ($action) in that TEMP table   ALL    the Operations performed.    I will need to INSERT after the MERGE statement specifying the appropriate ($action) rows to INSERT    Finally tally the contents of the TEMP table by OPERATION TYPE for Admin record keeping.  That is if I can figure out how to get ALL OPERATIONS Accounted for in the Temp table

Comment: Thank you "Earl' notice my temp table "#TheTempTableName".I am using it to harvest rows that are,after the completion of the MERGE, INSERTED into the 'DIM' table. Am I confusing this temp table with the OUTPUT clause content somehow?  My statement above is (Thank GOD) excellent I recently added an additional MERGE cond.for WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE to address rows missing from the incoming data. Since its missing source data the resulting UPDATE which actually retires rows in the DIM table with an UPDATE statement doesn't add rows to the #TheTempTableName" which I am using for a final INSERT.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your further comments i think the main issue is how you handle the type 2 updates.  The quick answer is you need two operations of UPDATE (insert/update); and DELETES are not really DELETES but UPDATES on the timestamp.

I have formulated a sample query below how to handle type2 updates and the results should be self explanatory.  I have tried doing a double operation on the UPDATE merge and it is interesting it cannot do it and gives an error: ***"An action of type 'INSERT' is not allowed in the 'WHEN MATCHED' clause of a MERGE statement."***  So i think there is no choice but to split the update and insert of the UPDATE statement.

The last consideration is also the DELETE that manifest as an update.  I have handled it as well in the code below how to determine when an action of UPDATE is really a DELETE.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _a
CREATE TABLE _a (
    id int
,val int
,fromdate datetime
,todate datetime
,isactive bit
)

INSERT INTO _a
select 1,100,'2015-Jan-1',NULL,1
UNION ALL select 2,200,'2015-Feb-1',NULL,1
UNION ALL select 3,300,'2015-Mar-1',NULL,1

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #data
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #outputdata

select * INTO #data from _a
select TOP 0 action=CAST('' as varchar(10)),* INTO #outputdata from _a

DELETE #data where id = 3
UPDATE #data set val = 2000 where id = 2
INSERT INTO #data
select 4,400,GETDATE(),NULL,1

--select * from #data

-- _a is your data warehouse table using type2

BEGIN TRAN

select Note='OLD STATE OF _a',* from _a

select Note='NEW SET OF DATA',* from #data


MERGE dbo._a T
USING (
    select id,val from #data
) S
ON (S.id = T.id)
WHEN MATCHED
AND ((S.val <> T.val OR (S.val IS NOT NULL AND T.val IS NULL) OR (S.val IS NULL AND T.val IS NOT NULL)))
THEN UPDATE SET  
        todate   = GETDATE()
    ,isactive = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN INSERT (id,val,fromdate,todate,isactive)
        VALUES (id,val,GETDATE(),NULL,1)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE --AND T.id IN (SELECT id FROM #data)
--THEN DELETE TYPE2
THEN UPDATE SET  /*NO-PK*/ 
        todate   = GETDATE()
    ,isactive = 0
OUTPUT $action as Action
    ,ISNULL(inserted.id,deleted.id)  as id
    ,ISNULL(inserted.val,deleted.val)  as val
    ,ISNULL(inserted.fromdate,deleted.fromdate)  as fromdate
    ,ISNULL(inserted.todate,deleted.todate)  as todate
    ,ISNULL(inserted.isactive,deleted.isactive)  as isactive
INTO #outputdata;

select Note='Logs Output',* from #outputdata

-- FIND THE NEW RECORD
INSERT INTO _a (id,val,fromdate,todate,isactive)
SELECT a.id,a.val,GETDATE()+.000001,a.todate,a.isactive
FROM #data a
INNER JOIN #outputdata b
on a.id = b.id
WHERE b.action ='UPDATE'

select Note='NEW STATE OF _a',* from _a

SELECT Note='Real Action',d1.id,action=CASE WHEN action='UPDATE' AND d2.id is null then 'DELETE' ELSE action END
FROM #outputdata d1
LEFT JOIN _a d2
on d1.action ='UPDATE' and d1.id = d2.id and d2.isactive =1

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

The results will be:

```
+-----------------+----+-----+-------------------------+--------+----------+
|      Note       | id | val |        fromdate         | todate | isactive |
+-----------------+----+-----+-------------------------+--------+----------+
| OLD STATE OF _a |  1 | 100 | 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NULL   |        1 |
| OLD STATE OF _a |  2 | 200 | 2015-02-01 00:00:00.000 | NULL   |        1 |
| OLD STATE OF _a |  3 | 300 | 2015-03-01 00:00:00.000 | NULL   |        1 |
+-----------------+----+-----+-------------------------+--------+----------+

+-----------------+----+------+-------------------------+--------+----------+
|      Note       | id | val  |        fromdate         | todate | isactive |
+-----------------+----+------+-------------------------+--------+----------+
| NEW SET OF DATA |  1 |  100 | 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NULL   |        1 |
| NEW SET OF DATA |  2 | 2000 | 2015-02-01 00:00:00.000 | NULL   |        1 |
| NEW SET OF DATA |  4 |  400 | 2019-01-31 09:49:45.943 | NULL   |        1 |
+-----------------+----+------+-------------------------+--------+----------+

+-------------+--------+----+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
|    Note     | action | id | val |        fromdate         |         todate          | isactive |
+-------------+--------+----+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
| Logs Output | INSERT |  4 | 400 | 2019-01-31 09:51:13.647 | NULL                    |        1 |
| Logs Output | UPDATE |  2 | 200 | 2015-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2019-01-31 09:51:13.647 |        0 |
| Logs Output | UPDATE |  3 | 300 | 2015-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 2019-01-31 09:51:13.647 |        0 |
+-------------+--------+----+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+

-- OPERATIONS 1 INSERT 1 UPDATE 1 DELETE
DELETE #data where id = 3
UPDATE #data set val = 2000 where id = 2
INSERT INTO #data
select 4,400,GETDATE(),NULL,1

+-----------------+----+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
|      Note       | id | val  |        fromdate         |         todate          | isactive |
+-----------------+----+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
| NEW STATE OF _a |  1 |  100 | 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NULL                    |        1 |
| NEW STATE OF _a |  2 |  200 | 2015-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2019-01-31 09:51:13.647 |        0 |
| NEW STATE OF _a |  3 |  300 | 2015-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 2019-01-31 09:51:13.647 |        0 |
| NEW STATE OF _a |  4 |  400 | 2019-01-31 09:51:13.647 | NULL                    |        1 |
| NEW STATE OF _a |  2 | 2000 | 2019-01-31 09:51:13.733 | NULL                    |        1 |
+-----------------+----+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+

+-------------+----+--------+
|    Note     | id | action |
+-------------+----+--------+
| Real Action |  4 | INSERT |
| Real Action |  2 | UPDATE |
| Real Action |  3 | DELETE |
+-------------+----+--------+
```